# Mocking in jest and express

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have some code in an Express route which talks to AWS Cognito and am having trouble working out how to mock it in tests.

```
cognitoExpress.validate(accessTokenFromClient, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return res.status(401).json({ error: err });

    res.json({ data: `Hello ${response.username}!` });
  });
```

Then in my test I want to say cognitoExpress.validate should be called once and return `{username: 'test user'}` so that it doesnt hit the network and doesnt actually call AWS Cognito

```
it('It should returns 200 with a valid token', async done => {
    const { cognitoExpress } = require('../helpers/cognitoExpress');

    // I have tried
    jest.mock('../helpers/cognitoExpress');
    // and this
    jest.mock('../helpers/cognitoExpress', () => ({
      validate: jest.fn()
    }));

    const token = 'sfsfdsfsdfsd';
    const response = await request.get('/').set('Authorization', token);
    expect(cognitoExpress.validate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(token);
    expect(response.body).toEqual({ data: 'Hello test user' });
    done();
  });
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

```
let spyInstance = undefined;

beforeAll(() => {
  spyInstance = jest.spyOn(cognitoExpress.prototype, "validate").mockImplementation(() => {
    // Replace the body of 'validate' here, ensure it sets
    // response body to {username: 'test user'} without calling AWS 
    ...
  });
});

afterAll(() => {
  expect(spyInstance).toBeDefined();
  expect(spyInstance).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});


it("It should call mocked cognitoExpress.validate once", async done => {
 ...
});
```

A similar and working [test](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/src/test/SampleModel.mock.test.ts) in my project. Instead of `cognitoExpress.validate` it mocks and tests `SampleModel.getData`

Answer (score 0):

Create file `../helpers/__mocks__/cognitoExpress.js` with mocked function you want to use. It is essential to call the folder `__mocks__`. You can modify a functions and return any data you want.

**example**

```
module.exports = { 
    validate: () => { username: 'test user' }
}
```

Now you can use `jest.mock('../helpers/cognitoExpress')`, but I recommend you to place it to some global or test setup file, not to separate tests.

[Jest Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)